# Efficient method for converting strings inside dataframes into arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm working with a dataset of multiple CSV tables. One of these tables which consists of two columns has floating-point arrays with 512 elements in the form of strings. The table is quite large, so I was wondering if there is any efficient method for transforming them into actual arrays in the form of columns, instead of simply iterating over the records.

The shape of the original Table: (A few million records, 2)

The desired output shape: (A few million records, 513)
Or maybe (A few million records, 2) but now the second column contains NumPy arrays and not strings.

Comment: I doubt you’ll be able to do much better than `Series.map()` or `Series.apply()`. What’s in the other column?

Comment: There have been a number of SO about parsing strings like this.  If a dataframe has arrays in a column, and is saved as a CSV, the `str` version of the array is written.  Parsing such a string isn't easy.

Comment: ```df["X"]=df["X"].map(eval)``` but please do clarify, how did you end up with string representation of list in your dataframe? ```pandas``` has it's ways of parsing ```csv``` like e.g. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

So, basically what you want is to convert the `strings` stored in the pandas dataframe having values of some floating points, like `'1.05'` to be converted into an array of numpy.

Well you can convert these strings to float as follows:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(float)
```

And then you can convert the whole dataframe into numpy array as follows:

```
array = df.to_numpy()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this wouldn't work. The strings found in the second column are like `'[1.0, 0.0, 0.547, ...]'`. Not that hard to parse, but I was wondering if there's a more efficient method for doing so.